# Array of dictionary value changes is reflect in all the values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have NSMutableArray and Added NSMutableDictionary

If i update one value for specific row then all the values changes in NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSIndexPath *qtyIndex

-(void)demoDefaultCartValues{

    [dict_CartItems setValue:@"Item 1 KK Demo" forKey:@"DIC_PRODUCT_NAME"];
    [dict_CartItems setValue:@" KK Demo" forKey:@"SELLER_NAME"];
    [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1" forKey:@"QTY_VALUE"];
    [dict_CartItems setValue:@"42" forKey:@"SIZE_VALUE"];
    [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1250" forKey:@"PRICE_VALUE"];
    [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1500" forKey:@"DISCOUNT_VALUE"];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        [cartListArray addObject:dict_CartItems];
    }

}

#pragma mark - DropDown Delegate

    -(void)dropDownView:(UIView *)ddView AtIndex:(NSInteger)selectedIndex{

        [[cartListArray objectAtIndex:qtyIndexPath.row] setValue:[sizeArrayList objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] forKey:@"QTY_VALUE"];

        NSLog(@"What %@",cartListArray);
    }
```

If I update qty 1 to 5 then all dictionary values QTY_Value changes to 5.

Comment: You are not creating new instance of dictionaries. You are using the same every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use new Objective-C features (more than 5 years old) to make this more readable. And add six different mutable dictionaries to the array:

```
NSDictionary* dict = { @"DIC_PRODUCT_NAME":@"Item 1 KK Demo",
                       @"SELLER_NAME":@" KK Demo",
                       @"QTY_VALUE": @"1",
                       etc.
                      };

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    [cartListArray addObject: [dict mutableCopy]];
```

and later:

```
-(void)dropDownView:(UIView *)ddView atIndex:(NSInteger)selectedIndex{

    cartListArray [qtyIndexPath.row] [@"QTY_VALUE] = sizeArrayList [selectedIndex];
}
```

cartListArray should be declared as

```
NSMutableArray <NSMutableDictionary*> *cartListArray;
```

Now what I would *really* recommend that you don't store a dictionary at all, but declare a model class. So you don't have to use strings for quantity etc. but NSInteger. Also that cartListArray isn't mutable if you don't want to modify it after it has been initialised. Keep things immutable whenever you can.

Comment: Mmmm! Thanks I will use new one.  Very simply way to read it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code uses the same dictionary and it's a refrence value , so it's a shallow copy of the same one , you may create a new one every iteration

```
 -(void)demoDefaultCartValues{


     for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

      NSMutableDictionary*dict_CartItems = [ NSMutableDictionary new];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@"Item 1 KK Demo" forKey:@"DIC_PRODUCT_NAME"];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@" KK Demo" forKey:@"SELLER_NAME"];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1" forKey:@"QTY_VALUE"];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@"42" forKey:@"SIZE_VALUE"];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1250" forKey:@"PRICE_VALUE"];
      [dict_CartItems setValue:@"1500" forKey:@"DISCOUNT_VALUE"];

       [cartListArray addObject:dict_CartItems];
     }

  }
```

Or you can use `copy` / `mutableCopy`

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
       [cartListArray addObject:[dict_CartItems mutableCopy]];
     }
```

Comment: Its demoDefaultCartValues call only one time for initialization.  then after edit its reflecting in all values.

Comment: Yes Its helps :D

Comment: Sh_Khan Thanks for your inputs Its work with MutableCopy for me..  the logic was out of my mind,  Thanks for the inputs Its really valuable.

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious

when you are adding `NSMutableDictionary` to array, array have the reference of that dictionary inside.

Now what you are doing is inserting same dictionary multiple times in array. so when you change a single object in array. all the places are get effected.  keeping same object of Dictionary always causes this issue.

Solution for this problem is create a new object every time before you insert into array.

Hope it is helpfult to you

Comment: I got it let me try! So again I need to have all they keyvalues for the new dictionary which i am creating.:D

Comment: @kiran Thanks , hope it is helpful

Comment: @kiran You don't need to create tall key values again ,  you can copy it. like NSDictionary *dict = [yourGlobalDict copy]

Comment: Yes Its work with MutableCopy since my dictionary value is changeable.

Comment: mutableCopy creates a copy of a dictionary, whether that original dictionary is mutable or not. copy creates an immutable copy of a dictionary, whether that original dictionary is mutable or not, with an optimisation: For an immutable dictionary, copy returns the same object with an additional reference count.

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks , I know that .but it is bad to create nsmutablearray with nsmutabledictionary isn't it ?. so i suggest copy there instead of mutablecopy